# Configure DNS for root domain on Namecheap

Tags: heroku, dns, namecheap

Relatively new to coding and was looking for some help on configuring the DNS for a root domain. I've been following [this heroku guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-root-domain) on adding a custom root domain and am currently stuck since the guide doesn't have specific rules on if your DNS provider is Namecheap (where I got my domain from).

To clarify, I have the domain gperalta.com and would like it to show the page I made at https://guarded-caverns-49596.herokuapp.com/. The closest I've been to having this work is having Namecheap redirect from gperalta to the herokuapp URL. But I'd like the URL itself to remain as 'gperalta.com' instead of defaulting back to the herokuapp URL.

Namecheap lists a Type, Host, Value, and TTS under their Advanced DNS Section. For reference, here are the options for what you can choose for Type:

- A Record
- A+ Dynamic DNS Record
- AAAA Record
- CNAME Record
- NS Record
- SRV Record
- TXT Record
- URL Redirect Record

Haven't been able to find anything on Namecheap (closest answer I found involves using an IP address, but heroku doesn't keep a consistent IP for apps) or stackoverflow so far, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a programmer's forum. Please post only questions related to software development. Questions about the use of some web site are considered off topic.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you get started. https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9737/2208/pointing-a-domain-to-the-heroku-app

In the future, Namecheap has an always-accessible 24/7/365 Live Chat and ticket platform so you should expect to get answers quicker.